# Access Google Photos through Google Drive is not working

Tags: google-drive-api, google-photos

We've been using Google Drive to fetch Google Photos metadata and to access photos through the following url

https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?authuser=0&sz="size"&id="photoId"

with the correct access token.

Metadata continues to work and drive url is giving a 404 http error (not found).

It was working ok, until some days ago (i.e. we first noticed it 2017/12/14). Probably this is related with changes going on with drive.
Is this an expected behaviour? What is the correct API to access Photos now?

Comment: have you checked the red text at the top of this page? https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/Y9VY7ZeXZvw;context-place=topicsearchin/drive/authorid$3AAPn2wQeStoYc3kUMYgclBgLWJFOusdiQnFciSnijJYd-pUgAi9YkjSOduPQVYhPS7epvzeQ4qCdz%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false). Try to clear your [cookies and cache](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/32050?hl=en), use an [incognito](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en)/[private window](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fkb%2Fprivate-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH5YTK-xMxBa1T3e2zbtbk-KMA4Ew), disable all browser [extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/187443?hl=en)/[add-ons](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fkb%2Fdisable-or-remove-add-ons&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGd7cm5vfVHX9C4-Ur9LViGVCN_jw)/[plug-ins](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142064?hl=en) and/or try a different browser to see if this is a browser related issue.

Answer (score 0):

this is happening in production on an iOS app and we do have multiple users complaining every day.

As a test case we did the following:

1 - go to Google Photos app and did check the option to show photos & videos in Google Drive;

2 - try to clear safari history;

3 - login again.

The result is the following:

1 - we do have success requesting several pages with photo-metadata through Google Drive api v3;

2 - Through the id that we get for each photo we do try to request an image for a specific size through 
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?authuser=0&sz="size"&id="photoId"

Step 2 fails with a http 404 and did not change nothing on our side. It is happening in all devices that we tested, which means that something changed or is not working properly with drive.

Meanwhile we've been told by someone (not Google) that Google Drive is no longer the best way to access Google Photos. Because this data source is in our product, it is important to know what is the correct / best api to access Google Photos now.